# Is it permissible to replace a tab bar with something that looks like a tab bar using i.e. a segment control or custom buttons etc.?

Tags: ios

It would be relatively straightforward to replace the tab bar with a segment control, or a view containing a series of custom buttons etc.
In this way one could have something that looks like a tab bar but the selected icon's color could be anything rather than the blue for a selected icon on a tab bar.

However is such a thing permissible or would it be rejected from the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to predict in advance what an app reviewer will do on any given day.  I'd say if it looks good and doesn't confuse the user then you've got a good shot.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen several apps that do this type of thing.

Read section 10 of the App Store Review Guidelines (log into your developer account at developer.apple.com to see this), and also the [iOS UI guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).